# Symfony 4 how to set a global parameter for use in twig

Tags: symfony, symfony4

I am after being able to set a parameter from my controller that can be accessed in twig to determine if the user is on an admin area or not to display an extra menu.

So perhaps I have an admin controller and inside the contractor I set a bool parameter to true as admin:

```
$this->isAdminArea = true;
```

Then in the template I need an if:

```
{% if isAdminArea %}

{% endif %}
```

And other controllers will either set $this->isAdminArea =false or somehow have it set default to false.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can define a global twig variable in config as stated in [Symfony documentation](https://symfony.com/doc/3.4/templating/global_variables.html):

```
# config/packages/twig.yaml
twig:
    # ...
    globals:
        isAdminArea: false
```

And then override it in your controller whenever it needs to be `true`.

In your specific case it's also possible to just set the default value in place, using either the [default](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/filters/default.html) or [defined](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/tests/defined.html) Twig filters

```
{% if isAdminArea|default(false) %}

{% endif %}
```

```
{% if isAdminArea is defined %}

{% endif %}
```

In the later case it doesn't matter to what value you'll set this into your admin controller, even `false` will do the job, which may be counter-intuitive.

Using a filter has the advantage of keeping all related bits into the same place, so unless you have the same check in multiple templates it should be considered more readable/maintainable solution.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. How would I override it in the controller? I’ve only come across a way to access it but can’t find anything to set it.

Comment: Never mind I see you use a service. Thanks for the help

Comment: In the controller you just pass a value with the `data` array argument of the  `render()` function. Values passed there will override Twig's globally defined ones